# Using Polymer Inside Django

Tags: django, polymer

I have a Django project already running with its UI created using Bootstrap and some custom CSS, JS.

Currently going through the Polymer Starter project, I want to do a UI makeover for my Django project using Polymer. Being a beginner with Polymer, my first question is, Is it feasible?

If yes, I would like to know from where should I start? I am not getting should I just remove all bootstrap and CSS already used and start replacing my old elements with newer Polymer elements? I have tried including Polymer elements in Django templates, but it doesn't seem to work this way.

I am just not getting the steps to follow for such a UI makeover.

Any piece of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure! But it would probably be easier if you use Django Rest Framework, and forget about django templates.

Comment: chomestatus.com does exactly this

Answer (score 5):

Refer to this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/polymer-dev/django/polymer-dev/N2R8qknalOI/58ZhC1gWFh4J.

You should be able to wrap Polymer elements in Django templates. They are just static files. Just make sure you are using {% verbatim %} tags to wrap around your polymer elements.

However, if you are going for a complete UI makeover, use AJAX calls to the REST services running in the background on Django. Or if you do not want to use django-rest-framework or tastypie or something new, you can slightly modify your existing view functions to serve JSON that packs all the data you need for a dynamic page.